# Vertical/horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus

We know  that for rational functions

$$f(x)/g(x)$$

vertical asymptotes are defined as the lines  $x=x_0$ where $g(x_0)=0$, and for horizontal asymptotes it is the limit as $x$ approaches $\infty$ or $x$ approaches $-\infty$.  My question is the following: what is the relationship between vertical and horizontal asymptotes?  For instance, if we have

$$y=f(x)$$

and we  express $x$ as function of $y$, or

$$x=f^{-1}(y),$$

is the horizontal asymptote of inverse function the same as the vertical one of the original?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Geometrically, both functions have the same graph and consequently the same asymptotes

Comment: so it means that if $x=x_0$ is vertical asymptotic of $f(x)$,it is the same one of it's inverse?

Comment: let take  example $y=x/(x-2)$,it's inverse is $y=2*x/(x-1)$

Comment: I think so at least i imagine it graphically, but i did not prove it analytically

Comment: Good: $x=2$ for the first and $y=2$ for the second seems to be right. but it does not prove it

Comment: look please answer below

Comment: A nice appreciated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, and the answer is not a simple "yes" or "no".

First of all, it's not quite true what you said about vertical asymptotes. If we're considering $y=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, points where $g(x)=0$ could give rise to either vertical asymptotes or to removable discontinuities. For example, $y=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ does not have a vertical asymptote at $x=0$

Now, when inverting a function $y=f(x)$, we need to be sure that the function $f$ is one-to-one. If it's not, we may be able to obtain various invertible functions by restricting the domain of $f$ in different ways. For example: There is no inverse for the function $f(x)=x^2$ defined on all reals, but if we restrict its domain to $[0,\infty)$, we get the inverse $f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt{y}$, while restricting the domain instead to $(-\infty,0]$ affords the inverse $f^{-1}(y)=-\sqrt{y}$.

If $f$ is a function with a vertical asymptote at $x=a$, and we've got some interval with $a$ on its boundary and on which $f$ is one-to-one, then yes. That vertical asymptote will turn into a horizontal asymptote for $f^{-1}$.

I'm assuming here that we're talking about simple types of asymptotes. Check out the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin\frac1x}{x}$ for an example of how weird things might get. You're going to have a hard time finding an interval on which to invert that function and see a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: thanks very much for pointing this

Comment: thanks my friend,thanks for pointing all the facts

Comment: nice answer....

Comment: that why +1 and good luck

Answer (score 1):

> is the horizontal asymptote of inverse function the same as the vertical one of the original?

For functions of the form $f(x)=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}, c\neq 0$, this statement is true. The inverse is $f^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{dx-b}{-cx+a}$.

Comment: thanks for help my friend,+1